# A house facing North and South, but not other directions

Tags: situation

How to build a house which faces to both North and South only, but not other directions such as East and West and North East?

Comment: Almost any terraced house would do

Comment: @Strawberry should be an answer, not a comment ;-)

Comment: this seems a little broad. For example, what is meant by "Facing?" Don't most houses "face" only one direction, i.e. where the front door is?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic, with our custom 'not fully defined' off topic reason, until this is [edit]ed to be less broad and to have a confirmable answer.

Comment: The edit did nothing to address the biggest question and source of ambiguity in this puzzle - as @MMAdams asked, "what is meant by 'Facing?'"  Various answers here interpret this in different ways, with very different results.  Without (at minimum) that clarity, this question is still not sufficiently defined to be reopened.

Answer (score 30):

You could argue that the following house works:

> [image]

Though:

> whether anyone would let you build it is another question

Note:

> in case it isn't clear from the picture, the 'outside' wall faces north everywhere since it faces away from the south pole, and the 'inside' wall faces south everywhere since it faces towards the south pole.

Comment: This reminds me oddly of a Biology class I took once.

Comment: What on Earth is this o.O

Comment: Should be the accepted answer for the handdrawn red circles.

Comment: There is no place like home, except if you live here

Answer (score 22):

You could do that in a town near me.

> [image]

Comment: How does this not face east and west?

Comment: If you built the house where I drew one, and faced in the direction that I drew, it would not be facing east or west. It would directly be facing North, and also be facing South (road), and also indirectly North (road).

Comment: @djsmiley2k A house is defined to "face" the direction of its front door. The front door of a house on the South side of South Rd would have a North-facing door on South Rd and would face no other directions.

Comment: For those confused: _North_ and _South_ are names of things (streets in this case), not directions.  Question should be tagged with _wordplay_ as this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 21):

You could simply

> Make it hexagonal. Orient it so that one wall faces north, and one south. The Others will face NE, NW, SE, SW. None face due east or west.

Note: The question has been edited. This answer satisfied the original conditions but is no longer valid.
With the new conditions, it would be easy to

> wait until the earth's core cools sufficiently (you could work on some of the unsolved pse puzzles to pass the time) and then build yourself a cylindrical house through the center of the earth with one end facing north and one end facing south. Easy peasy, if somewhat lacking in charm and airiness.

Comment: Or almost any shape really

Comment: @somebody If it's regular, it has to have 2*X sides where X is an odd number. If it's irregular, any number of sides greater than 3. (So that you can still have one side facing north and one facing south.)

Answer (score 18):

> You build a house all the way around the world at the equator. Then there are only 2 outer walls, facing north and south. If you go east or west inside the house, you will come back to where you started and never encounter an outer wall.

Comment: Why the equator

Comment: @somebody it doesn't strictly have to be at the equator, as long as the house loops around, and the north and south poles are on different sides. The equator was just the simplest to describe.

Comment: This is then essentially the same as boboquack's answer, except he kept it small by putting it near a pole.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I had literally no idea what I was looking at with that answer.  This one is much more clear and gives a specific example (at the equator) instead of just any equi-latitude circle.

Answer (score 10):

> A stretched out house that tapers to points on the east and west would only have two faces, north and south.

Comment: That's... actually quite ingenious, I hadn't thought of that. +1, and welcome to PSE!

Comment: This one was my first thought -- and far more buildable than most of the other answers.   I don't personally count a hexagonal house as completely not facing  E-W .

Answer (score 7):

> Build a house that faces North, South, East and West. Then build two more houses, immediately ajoining the first, on the East and West sides.

The result:

> The first house now faces North and South, but without any outside walls on its sides, it will not be facing East or West

credit to Strawberry for the idea.

Comment: +1 for a realistic answer. So realistic that it happens often in reality.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the fashion for environmentally friendly houses.

> Build the house through a hill, so that it only has two external walls and the sides are inside the hill. This gives good heat insulation, making it energy-efficient.

I have actually seen a house like this, although I don't have photos.

Comment: Great minds think alike...

Comment: @AndyT, especially when they've both passed close to VH many times...

Answer (score 5):

If you built a house where

> The north facing wall is straight, and the south facing wall is also straight, but the east and west walls curve in semi-circles, that house could be said to face both North and South, but not East or West.

Comment: I'm not sure about curves (there's at least one point that's due East/West), but a hexagon might work. The walls would face North and South (and North-east, North-west, South-east and South-west) but *not* (due) East and (due) West.

Answer (score 3):

Build this, exactly centered on the North (resp. South) Pole:

> [image]

All inner windows face North (resp. South), all outer ones face South (resp. North).

The house is square and symmetrical; the fourth wall is not visible in the drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Make the house like a lean-to, with the "leans" facing north and south.  the east and west sides do not have any faces (they are open), so it doesn't technically face in those directions...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea

> We can build a house (but perhaps it is uninhabitable !!)... in such a way that circular roof points to East and a circular floor points to West and have doors / windows on North and South sides.

That satisfies your requirements perhaps!!

Answer (score 1):

I assure these houses are facing north and south i live there :)
[image: HERE IS AN EXAMPLE]

[Map here](http://mapper.acme.com/?ll=34.49136,-5.50687&z=19&t=H&marker0=33.65278%2C-5.04167%2CDa%C3%AFt%20Aoua&marker1=34.49136%2C-5.50687%2C24.5%20km%20ExSE%20of%20Province%20de%20Sidi%20Kacem)

Comment: Is this Wile E Coyote's preferred online mapping software?

Comment: here in morocco we can't use google satellite images, without using VPN, so i prefer using this.

Answer (score 0):

> Build a house on the equator shaped like an almond--the long axis runs along the equator and the house protrudes north and south of the equator while tapering down to a point when the north and south walls meet on the equator. Your house now only faces north and south. [image: puzzle answer]

Comment: Why the equator

Answer (score -1):

A

> Space station should fulfill these requirements if it orbits around the equator.
>  It always faces the North and the South as in northern and southern hemisphere of Earth.
>
>  [Apparently a compass works in outer space though](https://www.spaceanswers.com/deep-space/apart-from-andromeda-are-any-other-galaxies-moving-towards-us/).

Comment: And why would a house directly under the space station not work?